# Using enums as object IDs

Tags: oop, enums, identity, haxe

I'm currently making a project. In this project, many objects have an ID that is used to get the properties and behaviors of an entity from the config files in different parts of code.

I'm using String as ID, that suits me well, but there are some problems:

1. The typos cannot easily be found;
2. There's no code completion, so I need to remember all the IDs

I'm thinking of using enum structure as object ID. This should solve all those problems. I wish to know, **is there any pitfalls of using enum as entity identificator?**

Comment: You can always declare string constants, can't you? It solves both of your problems.

Comment: I think this is some equivalent to enums, isn't it?

Comment: I don't know much about haxe. If they are the same thing in haxe, then use it. Some programming languages don't allow strings to be the underlying value of enums.

Comment: I meant, there's no big difference between using _ABILITY_XXX_ and using _Ability.Xxx_, isn't it?

Comment: You're right, I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quite a few pitfalls with using enums as IDs:

- *comparison* : You can't compare two enum instances directly with `==`, you need to either use `switch` or `a.equals(b)` or `Type.enumEq(a,b)`
- *serialization* : [As you can see](https://try.haxe.org/#1348D), Json serialization is not obvious.
- *representation* : underlying representation differs for each platform.

IMHO, besides these, the main pitfall is that the enum representation may change if you add enum items, as their representation contain their index in the enum.

So if you update your code from `enum ID { Foo; Bar }` to `enum ID { Zero; Foo; Bar; }`, the Foo and Bar values will have their indexes changed, potentially leading to unexpected behaviour.

This is a major issue if you plan to serialize and store these values.

I think your best option would be to use `@:enum abstract` as per https://haxe.org/manual/types-abstract-enum.html

This way, you get the best of both worlds: your IDs are actual runtime strings, but the compiler knows which values are expected and you get strict typing.

Comment: I also recommend `@:enum abstract`